# why am i encountering the " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml' " in ROS?

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, ros

I have recently begun to learn ROS.
whilst running a node file in pycharm, I'm encountering the aforementioned error.

my interpreter is *python2.7* and I do have *yaml* installed for *python2.7*. I have tried adding a path to the *yaml* folder but it's still not working. I'm using *Ubuntu 18.04*.

error message in terminal:

[image]

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundErrors` usually happen when a module isn't found. Try installing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
pip install PyYAML
```

to install PyYAML